# Count a Count with Django Aggregation through multiple Many to Many fields

Tags: django, django-orm, django-aggregation, django-annotate

Given a Django model with two M2M fields:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publishers = models.ManyToManyField(Publisher)
```

And starting from a queryset of Authors:

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(...)
```

How can I [annotate a count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) of the number of publishers (non-exclusive) the author has.... interacted with?

I can get the number of books the author has:

```
authors.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
```

But what I want is a count of the number of publishers for all books.

For example, if the data was like this:

```
Book | Authors | Publishers
B1     A1        P1, P2
B2     A2, A1    P1
B2     A2        P1, P2, P3
...
```

The resulting annotated counts would be:

```
Author |  Publishers
A1        3 (B1-P1, B1-P2, B2-P1)
A2        4 (B2-P1, B3-P1, B3-P2, B3-P3)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
authors.annotate(num_publishers=Count('book__publishers')).values('id', 'num_publishers')
```

The result will be:

```
<Queryser [{'id': 1, 'num_publishers': 10}, {'id': 2, 'num_publishers': 2}, ... ]>
```